# Can I make a GUI with Python without any extraneous software?

Tags: python, user-interface

I've been looking for ways to make a GUI with a .py file, and have so far only found frameworks and modules like Tkinter. However, my ultimate goal is for this code to run on a lot of computers that don't necessarily have these modules installed. The machines are only guaranteed to have Python on them. Does anyone know a way to make a GUI under these restrictions?

Comment: With these restrictions you will have to create own Framework working on all machines - it is many years of work :)

Comment: Windows? Linux? Note that Tkinter is included in most all standard Python distributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to ship your application with those modules as a part of it; the user's computer doesn't need to have the GUI framework installed if you provide it.

What you're asking would essentially require you to write an entire GUI framework, which would give a result that would be similar or worse - with a LOT more work.